# Reason for less or almost no research papers from PhD students in India

Tags: phd, reference-request, india, qualitative-research

It is evident from the stats of some reputed journals and conferences that Ph.D. students from India are getting hard to publish at least some research papers while other countries are publishing many productive research papers.

It is not a reason that there are fewer Ph.D. researchers. In fact, there are enough Ph.D. researchers in India. But most of them are published in low-quality or secondary journals.

I want to know the *key* and broad reason(s) for such phenomena. I am guessing three main reasons related to academia. One is less grip/expertise among the student community on the areas at the fundamental level and another reason is their less or no familiarity with the English language and publication skills. The last reason is the lack of funding, infrastructure, etc.

But I'm interested to know whether any study or statistics give reasons or insights on this. Is there any study that explicitly comments on the lagging of Indian Ph.D. students in top-tier publications compared to the leading countries?

Comment: I would say English language skills in India are considerably higher than in some other countries that do have many publications. I would also point out that there are many Indian scientific journals and some researchers/institutions might prefer to publish there. Let us see if someone comes up with some stats...

Comment: just to make sure. This is a reference request right?

Comment: This is too broad - the list of reasons can be long...

Comment: @BoatyMcboatface yeah.

Comment: @SolarMike But I am asking for key reasons only.

Comment: I think one thing you missed is academic migration. Many of the best Indian students are no longer in India. After all, why do your (PhD-)studies in India if you are exceptional enough to get a place at a more prestigious and better funded university in Europe or the US? This is of course related to the other points, but sadly it is also self-reinforcing as it leads to Indian universities being perceived as second rate places filled with second rate people, so future students have a further incentive to look for other options. I'm not sure where to get good data on that though.

Comment: Compering to China and US or EU. India have lowest budget for research

Comment: The question is also oddly phrased: PhD students are not the only ones conducting research

Comment: @Spark I am interested regarding PhD students only.

Comment: So just Indian PhD students? Or PhD students in India?

Comment: @Spark PhD students in India.

Comment: Then your first sentence makes no sense. How is it evident? Do you know percentages of publications by Indian PhD student lead authors? Also the entire question presupposes that students are the main drivers of research in India, which is really not obviously true.

Comment: @Spark yeah, I haa statistics of some reputed journals in which almost no Indian University has papers in it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lack of research funding as SSimon mention seems to the most likely reason for a poor research culture and hence Indian based journals. There is a well worn track of academics being trained overseas and returning. This approach however means that there is a poor academic culture based in India probably.

[India’s investment in research is a measly 0.62 percent of GDP.](https://www.orfonline.org/research/improving-research-in-india-introducing-undergraduate-research-in-higher-education-47713/)
Also from the report, there is an emphasis on the lack of undergraduate research resulting in only 0.5% of the student progressing with further PhD studies.

There seems to be an increase in the growth of high quality publications from India, especially in the area of chemistry - [Nature Index Report 2014.](https://www.natureindex.com/custom-reports/indian-science-ascending/high-quality-research-output-in-a-global-context/)